# Rails, favicon.ico not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is soo odd, I've been receiving:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/favicon.ico")
```

but I have the `favicon.ico` in my public directory... any ideas how to solve this? Nginx doesn't throw an error at all.

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the nginx.conf

Comment: Double check the file is in correct project's public dir. Try restarting nginx and rails app. If you are using some html for favicon in the html/layout, check that as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that nginx doesn't handle your static assets (since this request for static file goes to the ActionController). Check public root in nginx config file `nginx.conf`. 
Here is an example with Capistrano deployments:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  root /var/www/my_project/current/public;
}
```

And do you use a `favicon_link_tag` helper in your head :) ?

Answer (score 12):

Run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

then set

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in `config\environments\production.rb` file.
Then restart your server.
But I think `rake assets:precompile` is not required.

Comment: serve_static_assets was the key for me.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to keep config.serve_static_assets = false, which is recommended if you have nginx or apache, you can tell nginx to statically serve the files directly.  This is especially important for performance reasons, as you don't want rails serving these assets.

Below is a sample which also correctly has nginx statically serve the assets directory:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  root /var/www/my_project/current/public;

  location / {
        proxy_pass              http://mysite;
        proxy_redirect              off;
        proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO  https;
        proxy_set_header Host           $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size        10m;
        client_body_buffer_size     128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout       90;
        proxy_send_timeout      90;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;

        proxy_buffer_size       4k;
        proxy_buffers           4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size     64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size  64k;
    }

    # static resource routing - both assets folder and favicon.ico
    location ~* ^/assets/|favicon.ico {
        # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
            # http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
            expires 1y;
            add_header Cache-Control public;

            # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
            # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
            # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
            add_header Last-Modified "";
            add_header ETag "";
            break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the `favicon.ico` file isn't empty (byte size > 0).  For some reason I had an empty favicon.ico file which was triggering the same error, even though the file did exist.

Comment: If you run the install rake task from the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, it will put a link reference to favicon.ico in your application layout file, which is a null file by default (generated by the `rails new` command).

Answer (score 1):

delete slash sign before favicon.ico and try to use something like:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem when I first clone code from git repository and run with `RAILS_ENV=production`. Since there was no assets directory in my git repository, I needed to run `rake assets:precompile`.

Also I was run with rails s, so `config.serve_static_assets = true` worked. Thanks @Jiemurat