# Rails 3.1 favicon.ico not being served

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, favicon

Despite being in the `/public` directory, if I visit `http://site.example.com/favicon.ico` I get the 404 page. Interestingly, if I try to visit `http://site.example.com/500.html` I also get the 404 page leading me to believe that `/public` files are not being served up at all. I am running Nginx with Unicorn. Are there any settings in Rails that would disable the serving of `/public` assets?

**Edit**
My nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  server_name _;

  keepalive_timeout 5;

  # Location of our static files
  location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
    root /srv/ctr/current/public;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header  Cache-Control public;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # If you don't find the filename in the static files
    # Then request it from the unicorn server
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
      break;
    }
  }

  # error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  # location = /500.html {
  #   root /var/rails/testapp/public;
  # }
}
```

I do have `root :to => 'reports#index'` in my routes, but I don't see how that could make a difference.

**Solution**
I moved the line `root /srv/ctr/current/public;` to above `keepalive_timeout 5;`

Comment: I cannot confirm that Rails 3.1, Nginx and Unicorn ignore my favicon, 404.html or 500.html (from my public directory). Here is my config to check whether there are any differences: https://gist.github.com/1589113 Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your routes.rb to make sure you dont have a line such as

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

Also check Nginx.conf to make sure you have

```
root /path/to/app/public;
```

for your server / vhost.

Dave

Comment: Dave, are you sure that `root :to => "home#index"` could be a source for this error? I have that declaration and it can get my favicon etc. But the `root /path/to/app/public;` directive is my suggestion, too.

Comment: timbrandes, just checked and yes even with the route in favicon etc should work. It's been a while as our projects are multi-license, multi-company so I have a directive that sources the favicon depending on the hostname used (don't ask!!)

Comment: @detheridge02 you might want to edit that first part of your answer, as by being the accepted one it could mislead users who don't read the comments!

Answer (score 0):

[Rails, favicon.ico not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760661/rails-favicon-ico-not-found)

Configure your nginx .conf

`vim /etc/nginx/conf.d/your_project.conf`

```
server {
    ......

    # static resource routing - both assets folder and favicon.ico
    location ~* ^/assets/|favicon.ico {
        # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
            # http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
            expires 1y;
            add_header Cache-Control public;

            # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
            # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
            # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
            add_header Last-Modified "";
            add_header ETag "";
            break;
      }
}
```