# The asset "image.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to follow Agile development using rails 5.0 book. There I have loaded images inside `app/assets/images` directory manually just as told in the book.

Following is the line where it is showing error.

```
      <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image') %>
```

As I mentioned I loaded images called for ex `image.jpg`, and it throwing

**ActionController exception caught**

**Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Products#index**

`The asset "image.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline.`

When I checked in db seeded there is a image with url `image.jpg` but it is throwing error.

Comment: What is the HTML generated with that in the console?

Comment: you mean you want me to `inspect` the error page and tell ?

Comment: No. I mean the equivalent HTML code that is generated. If you inspect it you can see.

Comment: `<div class="line active">      &lt;%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image') %&gt;
</div>`

Comment: Do you use Paperclip for file attachments ? or do you store the image name Inside `image_url` field of Product model ? because in this case you have to make sure your image is located in the Rails pipeline (such `app/assets/images` ) .. or maybe do you store image as blob in database ??

Comment: For now I am just using them inside `app/assets/images`. They are just some manual added test data. So I haven't implemented paperclip yet.

Comment: `image_url` column has the name of the image file which are in `app/assets/images`

Comment: well basically you just have to make sure "image.jpg" is located in `app/assets/images` I can't see any other reason triggering this error message ... check spelling, upper case ...

Comment: if you can't find any error, you would probably check your asset pipeline https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708618/why-wont-rails-find-my-assets Please also confirm ou have your `image_tag` Inside a view file and maybe paste all your code

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue myself whilst following the book. You need to ensure that you have a file called `image.jpg` in the location `app/assets/images`. It's no good just having the filename in the `image_url` field in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to run `bin/rails db:seeds` after making changes to the seeds.rb file. Seems straight forward but as a new developer I sometimes forget (for about 30 mins) and wonder why it's not working.